# Upload image with google app engine fails

Tags: php, image, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to develop an image upload in my PHP google app engine app. First i am fetching the URL to use in the form.

```
$uploadUrl = CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('/upload/blob', [
    'max_bytes_per_blob' => 10000000, // 10 mb
    'max_bytes_total' => 10000000, // 10 mb
]);
```

Then in the upload handler i just do:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_files']['tmp_name'], "gs://strategic-atom-692.appspot.com/test.jpg");
var_dump(file_get_contents("gs://strategic-atom-692.appspot.com/test.jpg"));
```

And the answer i get is the following:

```
string(348) "Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 31540
Content-MD5: MzYzNDJhN2U2YTRkZGE5ZjFlZDJjOGM5NTE5MmY2ZDM=
X-AppEngine-Cloud-Storage-Object: /gs/app_default_bucket/fake-oYSdjQfQT-q6-UsXgqtFJg==
content-disposition: form-data; name="uploaded_files"; filename="testfile.jpg"
X-AppEngine-Upload-Creation: 2015-05-05 06:50:35.427419
```

Why am i not getting the image. I am using SDK version 1.9.18. 
Thank you.

Comment: Firstly, I'd suggest you to update to SDK 1.9.19. Secondly, are you testing this locally? Have you tried deploying the app?

Comment: I updated to 1.9.19, did not work. I am testing it locally on linux with php55 runtime environment. I have not tested it live yet since i want to debug it before.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately for this to work locally you'll need a modified PHP interpreter. However, you can try direct file upload which should work with stock PHP interpreter: https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2015/03/09/direct-file-uploads-for-php-5-5/

Comment: Thanks! This solved everything. This should really be mentioned here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/user_upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct answer to my question. :
https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2015/03/09/direct-file-uploads-for-php-5-5/